# How to increase space in my linux?

Tags: partitioning

[Please see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhCbN.png)

Anyone help me!

Comment: Your HDD seems to be full. Looking at the screenshot i"m afraid that you are going to delete your `/boot`-partition, that would render your system unbootable.

Comment: Please add some description of your problem into the question body

Answer (score 0):

To free up space from several locations use the following commands:

To clean the apt cache

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

To clean up old kernels

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

To remove packages and dependencies that are not required anymore by the ubuntu system:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

you can also use softwares like BleachBit find it here [BleachBit](http://apt://bleachbit)